# border-radius from container impacts inner div

Tags: html, css

When I have a `div` with a `border radius` and `overflow hidden` containing an inner `div` the "anti-aliasing" from the border seems to impact the inner div.

An example is better than a thousands words :

[JSfiddle example:](https://jsfiddle.net/qob6qjc6/2/)

```
.container{
    border:1px solid black;
    height:2rem;
    width:9rem;
    /**/
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius:0.4rem 0 0 0 ;
}
.sub{
    /*border-radius:0.4rem 0 0 0 ;*/
    background:purple;
    width:2rem;
    height:100%;
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="sub">


    </div>
</div>
```

So it's quite hard to see but if you zoom to the pixel level it's rather obvious. I know it's nit picky but I see it and it's annoying.

So I'm wondering what could be the solution for that ?

I tried setting a z-index on the inner div without luck.

Comment: Could you please explain what output you expect exactly?

Comment: This explains exactly what you need: http://tanalin.com/en/blog/2011/08/border-radius-rendering/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a problem with the overflow: hidden; line. My solution is a bit tricky. The container has border-box sizing, but the sub div doesn't, so this modified sub is actually 1px wider and 2px longer than that of yours, with same height as the container div.

I changed the .sub to an absolute div with the black border and border-radius itself, then position it -1px top and left to hide(actually the 3 borders are positioned exactly on top of the 3 borders of the container div) the black border of .sub, (remember to set border-right of sub div to none/0). This way, we get what you want.

```css
.container{
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height:2rem;
    width:9rem;
    border:1px solid black;
    border-radius: 0.4rem 0 0 0;
}
.sub{
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    left: -1px;
    box-sizing: initial;
    display: block;
    background:purple;
    width:2rem;
    height:100%;
    border:1px solid black;
    border-right: 0;
    border-radius: 0.4rem 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="sub">
          
        
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the most ideal solution, but you can apply an inset box shadow and then position the child element using `z-index`. Since the shadow is inset, you will need to `calc()` the width to account for the extra space:

https://jsfiddle.net/qob6qjc6/6/

```
.container{
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #000;
    height: calc(2rem + 2px);
    width: calc(9rem + 2px);
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius:0.4rem 0 0 0;
}
.sub{
    background:purple;
    width:2rem;
    height:100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1
}
```

This breaks if you stack the parent in the z order:

https://jsfiddle.net/qob6qjc6/7/

```
.container{
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #000;
    height: calc(2rem + 2px);
    width: calc(9rem + 2px);
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius:0.4rem 0 0 0;

    position: relative;
    /* as soon as you set the z-index on the parent, it breaks */
    z-index: 1;
}
.sub{
    background:purple;
    width:2rem;
    height:100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1
}
```